# Is there any android adt templates you would recommend?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Android Adt templates help you to get started with your new Android app by creating for you activities, services, broadcast, etc.

And doing all the heavy lifting for you, including registering your new item in the manifest file !

[image: new activity]

They are accessible in Eclipse, in the NEW wizard, in the ANDROID folder, new **Android object**.

[image: wizard]

And the best part is, you can add new ones !

Do you know any good adt templates to recommend, for both new android developers and seasoned ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `ActionBarSherlock` then you might want to use [these](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-adt-templates) rather than the default ones.